# Running AFNetworking 2 synchronously on a created background thread

Tags: ios, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I create a background thread to do a series of AFNetworking requests, and I want them to be in order. Some code:

```
dispatch_queue_t request_queue = dispatch_queue_create("someLabel", NULL);

dispatch_async(request_queue, ^{

    dispatch_semaphore_wait(self.mySemaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

    // AFnetworking request I want to be synchronous
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"foo": @"bar"};
    [manager POST:@"http://example.com/resources.json" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];

    ...
```

How do I make the AFHTTPRequest synchronous?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you should generate the NSURLSessionDataTask yourself. The AF Operation manager will enqueue the operation immediately (that's just what it does). If you create one yourself, you can call `resume` when you please or add the operation to your own queue as you please.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand... what do you mean by resume? Can you give me a code sample?

Comment: Docs are here - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionTask_class/Reference/Reference.html . It's really handy to know about when you don't just have simply data tasks, but also longer running upload or download tasks.